# How to find and copy only the first 100 .jpg files under the home directory, including all the subdirectories within?

Tags: scripting, find, cp, xargs

I coded like below:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' | head -n 100 | xargs -0 {} cp {} /home/rachael/backup
```

Error showed:

```
xargs: {}: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with my code and how can it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You're missing a `-I` in your `xargs` command to tell it what the `{}` is to be used for
2. The `-0` tells `xargs` to expect null-delimited input, but you're passing it newline-delimited input

So

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -print0 | head -zn 100 | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} /home/rachael/backup
```

If you have the GNU version of `cp`, you might want to use the alternate form

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -print0 | head -zn 100 | xargs -0 cp -t /home/rachael/backup
```

Comment: +1.  depending on what OP meant by "first" 100 files, it may also be worthwhile inserting a `| sort -V -z` before the `| head -zn 100`.

Answer (score 2):

[steeldriver pinpoints some of the issues with your command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541940/116858), but I just wanted to add a shorter solution using the `zsh` shell (as the question was not specific to any one shell):

```
cp -- *.jpg(.[1,100]) ~rachel/backup
```

This would copy the 100 first (by lexicographic ordering) regular files in the current directory that matches the globbing pattern `*.jpg`.

For the 100 oldest files by modification timestamp, use `*.jpg(.Om[1,100])`, and use a lower-case `o` instead of `O` to get the 100 most recently modified files. Use `n` in place of `Om`  to get numeric sorting of the filenames, and add `D` to also match hidden names.

Comment: Which also has the benefit of copying the file in a consistent order (see also the the `n` glob qualifier to use a numeric order as jpg files tend to have numbers in them). See also the `D` glob qualifier to also consider hidden jpg files or jpg files in hidden directories (like `find` does by default).